# jsonwebtoken causes unit tests to fail

Tags: java, spring, maven, unit-testing

I have an interesting problem regarding [json web token](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt). The moment I add this dependency to maven pom, my unit tests for Spring Rest Controller throw gibberish, like

```
ResultActions results = mockMvc.perform(post("/customers/" + customerId + "/orders")
.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(new Gson().toJson(order)));
```

is expected to give 200, but gives 400. What I've noticed upon investigating the issue is that the problem happens only for tests that test POST/PUT (transactional HTTP requests I guess I could call them). I've tried excluding dependency from testing using information in [this](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html) link, but to no avail. I'm not sure what other information to provide, because I really don't have the faintest idea as to what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue. The problem was dependency conflict. JJWT depends on Jackson and I've already been using GSON for my Jsons. Those two conflicted in a weird way. I've solved the issue by changing JJWT to another JWT lib.